# convert ms-access last() function to sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access

How to convert ms-access last() function to sql server 2008 equivalent query? code is

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Last([Title].[Number) AS Row_ID 
FROM [Title] 
HAVING (Last([Title].[Number]) Is Null)
```

Comment: You should explain what the LAST supposed to do in your query

Comment: is migrating to SQL 2012 an option ? [LAST_VALUE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh231517.aspx)

Comment: are you sure this query of yours select anything? I am worried about the NULL part. What is this query doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select Top 1 Number From
(
  Select Number From Title ORDER BY Number DESC
)
```

Answer (score 2):

It has no direct equivalent but can generally be achieved by combinations of `ORDER BY` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, or possibly `MAX` - if you provide more context and sample data then it is easier to give a definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [LAST_VALUE(Title.Number) over (...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sub-query with `ORDER BY` because sql-server doesn't guaranty order of rows without this clause . See the example.

```
declare @tbl table(f1 int, f2 varchar(10), d datetime)

insert into @tbl values (1,'1-first','20120917')
insert into @tbl values (1,'1-middle','20120918')
insert into @tbl values (1,'1-last','20120919')
insert into @tbl values (2,'2-just one','20120917')


select f1, (select TOP 1 f2 from @tbl t2 where t2.f1=t1.f1 order by d DESC) Last_f2
from @tbl t1
group by f1
```