# Access Last keyword query to SQL conversion

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I would like to convert an Access query with the last keyword to SQL Server 2005 but cannot figure it out any help is appreciated.

The query in Access is

```
SELECT field1, field2, Last(field3) , Last(field4) , Last(DateField) 
FROM table
GROUP BY field1, field2
HAVING (((Last(DateField)) Between #9/1/2012# And #9/30/2012#));
```

I have tried to sort Datefield in descending order in SQL and used the MIN keyword on datefield but to no avail, also in SQL I have to group by all the fields and not just 2 fields as in Access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281551/tsql-left-join-and-only-last-row-from-right

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert ms-access last() function to sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490325/convert-ms-access-last-function-to-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `MAX` instead of `LAST`, like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, MAX(field3) , MAX(field4) , MAX(DateField) 
FROM table
GROUP BY field1, field2
HAVING MAX(DateField) Between "9/1/2012" And "9/30/2012"
```

I don't understand this at all: *I have to group by all the fields*  If you group by all the fields, it's equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT`, and performing aggregate functions won't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Beth. I had to add MAX to the fields 3,4 andDateField in order to omit them from Group By It worked like a charm thank you.