# Converting an access Last() function into a SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, database-migration

I am attempting to convert this access function in a SQL equivalent.

```
Last([Delivery Table].[Advice Number]) AS [LastOfAdvice Number]
```

Since the last function does not exist in SQL I did this:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 [Delivery Table].[Advice Number] FROM
    (
    SELECT [Delivery Table].[Advice Number]   
    FROM [Delivery Table] ORDER BY [Delivery Table].[Advice Number] DESC
    ) AS [Advice Number Sorted]
) AS [LastOfAdvice Number]
```

I got the above solution from: [convert ms-access last() function to sql server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490325/convert-ms-access-last-function-to-sql-server-2008)

However, I am getting this error message:

```
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 137
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, 
subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is 
also specified.
```

It's confusing because I have already specified TOP above.
Any Ideas?

Edit:
This image shows the function used in access.
[image: Access Function]

Comment: You don't have a TOP in the sub query. That's what it is complaining about. Also as an aside, do you actually get the desired results from your Last() function in Access. It's a awful function that doesn't do what most people think it does, and IMHO should be removed.

Comment: Whether or not I am getting the correct result is irrelevant in this case unfortunately. I have been bought in on a massive migration project and need to migrate like-for-like into SQL Server as a number of things can stop working if I omitted anything. This involves having to use the horrible Last() function as well unfortunately.

Comment: No problem. Thankfully I don't think SQL Server is daft enough to have a direct Last() replacement. Max() as suggested will give you a repeatable reliable result.

Comment: What you are doing, even if it works, just gives `Max()`, not `Last()`. Might as well just use `Max()` as Gustav suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `subquery` only `TOP` clause is sufficient to access the last record of `[Delivery Table]` table :

```
SELECT TOP (1) dt.[Advice Number]   
FROM [Delivery Table] AS dt
ORDER BY dt.[Advice Number] DESC;
```

However, when you specify the `order by` clause in subquery you should have `top` clause inside `subquery`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work to a certain extent. I need to use aggregate data so need to group by the above query. Will I have to use CTE/Temp table to do this?

Comment: @RikuDas. . . What you want to achieve ?

Comment: I am trying to mimic the result set that I am getting in the access query. I'm not sure where this field is used, if at all, and for what. My primary concern is that we get the same exact results in the SQL query that I get for its access counterparts. I will be using the Access front-end with pass-through queries, so i need the results to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually replace *First* or *Last* with another aggregating function like *Min* or *Max* - with a little more meaning:

```
Max([Delivery Table].[Advice Number]) AS [LastOfAdvice Number]
```

Comment: Wouldn't Max/Min just give me the largest/smallest values? I need the Last/First values, not the largest/smallest.

Comment: Then you must define "first" and "last". Problem is, that when done - as @Minty states above - functions First() and Last() may or may not return the expect results, thus are close to being useless. At least, Max() will give the highest "Advice Number" which usually will be the latest (last recorded).

Comment: Unfortunately the Max value is not always the last value. The primary key Advice Number is not a Autonumber, but an Number field. The numbers are generated +1 in VB and some have been edited so they are not in incremental order as you'd expect.

Comment: If so, why did you try with `ORDER BY [Delivery Table].[Advice Number]`? But - include a timestamp field of data type _DateTime_ and order by (search) that.